# Proof that pressure rises in a fixed control volume

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

I am looking for a proof using Bernoulli's equation that that for $Q=(Area)(Velocity)$, $Q_{in}>Q_{out} \Rightarrow P_{inside}>P_{outside}$. I read that for a computer, if the case fans blow a higher volumetric flow rate in than out, then the PC case is positive pressure, however I seem unable to prove this. My attempt is shown below, with the assumption that $z_1=z_2$, $P_{1,g}=0$, and the subscript g indicates gage pressure. My control volume is the inside of a computer case, and subscript 1 represents outside of the control volume (flowing in), and subscript 2 represents inside the control volume (flowing out):

\begin{align} \frac{P_1}{\rho}+\frac{V_1^2}{2}+z_{1}&=\frac{P_2}{\rho}+\frac{V_2^2}{2}+z_{2} \\ \frac{V_1^2}{2}&=\frac{P_{2,g}}{\rho_{air}}+\frac{V_2^2}{2} \Rightarrow \\ \frac{P_{2,g}}{\rho_{air}}&=\frac{V_1^2-V_2^2}{2} \Rightarrow \\ P_{inside,g}&=\rho_{air} \frac{V_{entering}^2-V_{leaving}^2}{2} \end{align}

Since $V=\frac{Q}{A}$, then the pressure inside is also dependent on the area of a fan, which contradicts what I read saying $Q_{in}>Q_{out} \Rightarrow P_{inside}>P_{outside}$. This is a bit confusing to me and I'd appreciate any answers that I can get.

Comment: Can you define more of your notation? What does the $g$ subscript represent, and are $1$ and $2$ the same as "in" and "out" respectively?

Comment: Are you assuming that the air is incompressible?  You must not be assuming this, because, otherwise Qin=Qout.  Also. Is the fan inside the control volume or outside?

Comment: Is heat being released within the control volume?

Comment: In the particular case you mentioned Bernoulli equation is not applicable because viscous effects are dominant.

Comment: @Josh Can you give the source of where you read it plz ?

Comment: @J.A The source where I read this is: https://www.neweggbusiness.com/smartbuyer/over-easy/pc-cooling-how-to-set-up-computer-case-fans/

Comment: @AaronStevens I edited my original post to hopefully clear some things up further. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I suppose that I am since the assumptions that come along with using Bernoulli's equation are (1) incompressible (2) inviscous (3) along a streamline and (4) steady flow. Why does incompressibility imply that Qin=Qout? And is there another equation I could use to prove that if Qin>Qout for a computer, then Pin>Pout?

Comment: Incompressibility implies Qin=Qout because the mass flow rate is $\rho Q$, where rho is the density.  The answer to your other equation depends on what is going on inside the control volume.  Can you provide more details?